# Ubuntu OS for phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How can I download and use Ubuntu Touch on my Samsung Galaxy smartphone? I saw a video for downloading it on an Android smartphone and using it as a default OS. Is it really possible?

Comment: [See this](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices) for more info about Ubuntu Touch.